# Poset definition: Reduction to a point.

Tags: reference-request, definition, order-theory

I need the following object in my research:

A proper subset of a poset $\{x_k\}\subset P$ with $|\{x_k\}|>1$ is reducible to a point (a RAP) when for every $y\in P-\{x_k\}$, either $y\leq\{x_k\}$, $\{x_k\}\leq y$, or $\{x_k\}$ and $y$ are incomparable.

I have a hard time believing that no one has studied or defined such an object before in the poset literature, but I have not found it in Stanley or any other source. Does anyone know if this definition exists in the literature and if so where?

Comment: I think one could describe it as a fiber of an order embedding (which I'd guess is why you're thinking about it), but I don't think that'd help find any literature on it.

Comment: Right, but I believe it would be the fiber of just a homomorphism, as embeddings are injective?